# Python - conversion of string to list of sets

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, set

I have a list of strings like `['abc,bcd,cde,def,bcd', 'ijk,jkl', 'lmn,mno,nop,mno' ]` and I am trying to convert into list of sets of strings as given below

```
[{'abc','bcd', 'cde', 'def'}, {'ijk','jkl'}, {'lmn','mno','nop'}]
```

I have tried to loop through each item in the list and used a set() function to convert but it returned each character instead of a each string as shown below

```
L= ['abc,bcd,cde,def,bcd', 'ijk,jkl', 'lmn,mno,nop,mno' ]

for i in L:
     print(set(i))
```

output:

```
{'b','c','d','e','a','f'}
{'j','i','k','l'}
{'m','l','n','o','p'}
```

My desired output: `[{'abc','bcd', 'cde', 'def'}, {'ijk','jkl'}, {'lmn','mno','nop'}]`

Can you please give ideas on what am  I doing wrong.. (I am novice to Python)

Comment: `print(set(i.split(",")))` split string by comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fast and easy by just spliting the strings where you find commas.

```
string_list = ['abc,bcd,cde,def,bcd', 'ijk,jkl', 'lmn,mno,nop,mno']
string_sets = []

for string in string_list:
    string_sets.append(set(string.split(",")))
```